# Fetching data from database with integrity broken

Tags: c#, mysql, database, sql-server-2008

Should application expect the unexpected when fetching data from database? Lets say that we have stored an enumeration value in a column (int or text). When we return values from database, we cast the value to enumeration type. What if someone has altered data in database manually, and broke data integrity, so our cast is failing?

Another example would be when a data type in c# is of less range that equivalent field in database. If anyone puts value in this value manually, lets say to database max value, then application would throw out of range exception.

Should we and how handle this exceptions?

**Edit:** Since most of the answers are similar, I am going to rephrase the question. It is implied that there is exception logging in the application. The problem is: when user queries for some data, and the data is corrupted (not from application CRUD operations, but outside), data conversion from database to model will fail, and user will get no data at all. Is it acceptable to have such a state in application, since the application itself didnt cause it?

Validating data would create a big slowdown on data fetching. Imagine that you need to check each decimal value if its out of range?

Comment: You should handle this by taring and feathering the person who did that. The Cat-O-Nine is a broadly accepted alternative, that avoids the environmental impact of the tar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always took it to be standard practice to place any database interaction code in the datalayer with in `try...catch` blocks so that you can handle situations such as this in a civilised manner.

I don't check for every eventuality, but being able to log exceptions will prove useful when supporting your code in the long run.

In the case of a live system it's always good to have such information especially when you can accuse a customer of fiddling with things that they shouldn't have.

**edit**

As I said you can't check for every eventuality, but you can trap exceptions caused by situations such as casting a value to an enum that doesn't exist.

It isn't really possible to check for values that are out of range, other than the extreme e.g. a field unexpectedly comes back as `DBNull` or fails convertion from database datatype to model data type. In such a case handling the error and presenting the user with an error message or "VALUE UNKNOWN" type indicator should be okay.

The problem here is that you have a user who is changing data without using your application.

You may already be implementing `IDataErrorInfo` in your data model, specifically to validate user input, if not look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/98681/Validating-User-Input-WPF-MVVM) for an example, or maybe something similar.

But you can't really cope with 'corrupted' data being a valid value i.e. if your enum field was changed to one that was correct value wise but incorrect logically you wouldn't know until you came to use it that it was wrong.

A pragmatic approach has to be taken as you rightly said validation of thousands or even just hundreds of values being retrieved from the database would have an unexceptable hit on performance.

But saying "There's been an error, please contact your system administrator" or something similar is perfectly acceptable in my view.

Answer (score 0):

It depends, is that usually possible to happen?

In my case, what I do is to things:

1. Log everything the executable does (it can be usefull for that case to identify where it failled)
2. When running it with a batch file, check the exit status, if it's not 0 (a error occured), send an email for me!

With this, I know if something happened and I can prove that it wasn't my fault.

---

Regarding your update, I just can say it depends!

In my case, I build projects regarding functional data provided. And in all projects we have a set of requirements that the client needs to aprove (one might be the data from a table beeing in a certain way).

The client accepts the requirements and voilá! So, if something is alter it's not our fault and we are secured because the client accepts the requirements.

Comment: @Goran check what I said now.

Comment: If I understood you well, you are reffering to external data source, I am speaking about our application database? I am not sure how can you have a set of requirements on this things? Example: Decimal field in C# has precision of 29, SQL server Decimal has precision of 38. If someone enters a value in YOUR database that has 38 precision, application will break with exception. What kind of agreement can you make with customer about this and similar problems? Of course, it is assumed that database in on customers site.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've got fallible human beings mucking about with your database at a low level, then you should definitely perform such checks. The reason is that debugging is extremely expensive, and so when one of these errors does happen (as it inevitably will), as a defensive measure you should catch such errors as early as possible, rather than letting them propagate into your program and causing subtler, harder-to-find bugs elsewhere.

If it were "provably impossible" for a weird value to get into your database, one might argue that such a check is unnecessary. You could for example put a column constraint on your database columns. Even in that case, one might keep the code checks around anyway as a defensive measure, unless you can argue that such checks degrade the performance of your system (which they likely do not).

Comment: Checking the data integrity can be contraproductive. Please check my question, I have updated it.